# Visual Studio 2010 editions - switching from Premium (not a trial) to Ultimate trial and back again

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, trial

I have installed Visual Studio 2010 Premium RTM (not a trial) and would like to run the Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate Trial for a while.

What is the fastest way to switch to Ultimate trial and back again to the Premium?

My best idea:

1. not uninstalling the Premium edition.
2. running the [Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate Trial - Web Install](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=e2a1a098-995e-4468-816d-7fdbe0a64f38)
3. testing the Ultimate trial
4. uninstalling the Ultimate trial
5. repairing the Premium installation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the *safest* way would be to run the trial in a VM under VMWare or VirtualBox. I wouldn't trust different versions or levels of the same software to run nicely together.

But I'm inherently paranoid :-)

Comment: +1 Yes, or otherwise I'd do complete uninstall of the current version before installing either of the versions.